# Pattern matching with knex.js

Tags: javascript, regex, knex.js

I have the following query:

```js
const result = await knex('Words')
  .leftJoin('Active', 'Words.Column', '=', 'Active.Column')
  .leftJoin('Online', 'Words.Column', '=', 'Online.Column')
  .column(['Words.Column', 'TranslationEng'])
  .whereIn('Words.Column', sentenceArray);
```

Short description for the last line: a **sentenceArray**, that comes from an input-box (example: ['Hello there', 'Hi'] ) is matched with the data in my postgres-DB, namely the **Words.Column** (example: 'Hello there' and 'Hi').

My problem now: the sentenceArray may not always match the words in my DB. I think I need to add pattern matching in .leftJoin and .whereIn.

The goal is that the query is:

1. case insensitive
2. signs like * are ignored
3. words in parentheses are ignored.

Example: sentenceArray: [ 'Hello (Denis)*', 'HI' ] => should match: 'hello', 'hi' in my DB.

I already tried to work with "like/ ilike" for the case insensitivity and tried several combinations, f.ex.:

```
.leftJoin("Active", "Words.Column", "like", "%${Active.Column}%")
```

...but nothing worked. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

SQL `in` statement will look for the entire words, it's like a syntactic sugar for `or` operation.

What you need is to make a use of [`like`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-like/) operator with wild char `%`.

The target query should look like:

```sql
SELECT words.COLUMN, 
       translationeng 
FROM   words 
       LEFT JOIN active 
              ON active.COLUMN = words.COLUMN 
       LEFT JOIN online 
              ON online.COLUMN = words.COLUMN 
WHERE  words.COLUMN LIKE '%first-word%' 
        OR words.COLUMN LIKE '%second-word%'  ...
```

This query can be built with `knex`:

```js
const result = await knex('Words')
  .leftJoin('Active', 'Words.Column', '=', 'Active.Column')
  .leftJoin('Online', 'Words.Column', '=', 'Online.Column')
  .column(['Words.Column', 'TranslationEng'])
  .where((qb) => {
    sentenceArray.forEach((word) => qb.whereOr('Words.Column', 'like', `%${word}%`));
    return qb;
  });
```

#### Edit:

```js
const result = await knex('Words')
  .leftJoin('Active', 'Words.Column', '=', 'Active.Column')
  .leftJoin('Online', 'Words.Column', '=', 'Online.Column')
  .column(['Words.Column', 'TranslationEng'])
  .where((qb) => {
    sentenceArray.forEach((word) =>
      qb.whereOr('Words.Column', 'like', `%${word.replace(/\W+/g, '%')}%`)
    );
    return qb;
  });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :) This was very interesting! I tested your code and it works great for ignoring upper/lowercase. Do you have a suggestion how I can additionally ignore words in parentheses and signs like * ? F.ex. "Hi there* (Denis)" => "Hi there" (see question). I tried to complete your query by several different variations of: `%${word} [^(A-Za-z)]%`. But it doesn't work. Problem I see: parentheses and signs like * can be anywhere in the sentence.

Comment: Check my updated answer, it replaces all chars that are not words to sql wild case (`%`)

Comment: I don't agree using `LIKE` because it is very slow especially when your database grow large. Prefer using `FULLTEXT` index then filter them by using `MATCH`. Ex : `SELECT * FROM products WHERE MATCH(name, description) AGAINST('your keyword' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)`. I don't know yet how to build this query in knex

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html). Since knex doesn't have .regex() fn yet, .whereRaw has to be used.

Values within REGEXP quotes and between the | (OR) operator are treated as wildcards. Typically, REGEXP will require wildcard expressions such as '(.*)first_word (.*)' to work as '%first_word %'.

```
// create regex string from original sentence splitting each word
const regex = sentenceArray.replace(' ', ' | ');

const result = await knex('Words')
  .leftJoin('Active', 'Words.Column', '=', 'Active.Column')
  .leftJoin('Online', 'Words.Column', '=', 'Online.Column')
  .column(['Words.Column', 'TranslationEng'])
  .whereRaw(`Words.Column REGEXP ${regex}`);
```